# In snowflake or SQL, how will I convert a value in a column from 1_2_3_4 to A_B_C_D?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to convert values eg:

```
1_2_3_4 to A_B_C_D
2_3_4_5 to B_C_D_E

...

1_2_4_4 to A_B_D_D
```

I used below query but no luck.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1_2_3_4', '[0-9]', CHAR(CHR(ASCII('A')  + cast(REGEXP_SUBSTR($0, '\\d') as integer) - 1), 1, 0, 'c');
```

Comment: `SELECT TRANSLATE('1_2_3_4', '1234', 'ABCD')` - [TRANSLATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/translate)

Answer (score 1):

As suggest @LukaszSzozda in comments, you can use [`TRANSLATE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/translate) :

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('1_2_3_4', '123456789', 'ABCDEFGHI');
```

Return : `A_B_C_D`

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('2_3_4_5', '123456789', 'ABCDEFGHI');
```

Return : `B_C_D_E`

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
with test as(select '1_2_3_4' as exp1 union all select '2_3_4_5')
select *
  ,replace(
    replace(
     replace(
      replace(
       replace(
        replace(exp1
              ,'1','A')
            ,'2','B')
          ,'3','C')
        ,'4','D')
      ,'5','E')
    ,'6','F')
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build my own function for this and you can use Python UDFs. Something like this:

```
create or replace function digit_to_char(s string)
returns string
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'digit_to_char'
as
$$
def digit_to_char(s):
    res = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i].isdigit():
            res+= chr(ord('@')+int(s[i]))
            print(res)
        else:
            res+=s[i]
    return res
$$;
```

When called for different inputs:

```
select digit_to_char('1_2_3_4');   --A_B_C_D
select digit_to_char('1_3_4_6');   --A_C_D_F
select digit_to_char('2_3_4_5');   --B_C_D_E
```